# With the latest node v16.15.1 and npm 8.11.0 facing issue

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vue-cli

After updating the node to the latest 16.15.1

And tried npm install or npm ci getting the below error.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@4.5.13
npm ERR! Found: eslint@6.8.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint/node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   peer eslint@">=1.6.0 <7.0.0" from eslint-loader@2.2.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint/node_modules/eslint-loader
npm ERR!     eslint-loader@"^2.2.1" from @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@4.5.13
npm ERR!     node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint
npm ERR!       dev @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@"^4.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@">= 1.6.0 < 7.0.0" from @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@4.5.13
npm ERR! node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint
npm ERR!   dev @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@"^4.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@6.8.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   peer eslint@">= 1.6.0 < 7.0.0" from @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@4.5.13
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint
npm ERR!     dev @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@"^4.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

The workaround is to use --legacy-peer-deps with npm

Or do we have any better solution instead of accepting an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Comment: Wondering the same thing, updating to that version, can't build anymore, and the debug log is not all so helpful...

Comment: Right, but this question is closed @iBobb

Comment: Try searching the Vue CLI issues list next time ~ https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/7149

Comment: Do we have any solution for this?

Comment: The weird thing is ">= 1.6.0 < 7.0.0" should allow "6.8.0" so I don't understand what the problem is.  This could be a bug introduced to npm v8.11 because the problem doesn't happen with npm v8.1 and node v16.13.1